# Excluding files from tsconfig causes vscode to not work well with excluded files

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular app that has its typical components, storybook stories in those component directories and spec files as well.

Issue we're having is when we build our app it takes a long time.  I want to only build the typescript files and exclude spec and stories.

The issue with this is, in vsCode when you're in spec, stories files.  The paths aren't compiled and we have red lines all over the place.

Question is can we build with only certain files but use vsCode for all files.

Or have different tsConfig files for building vs VsCode.

Current include that breaks vscode for spec and stories files.

```
"files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
],
"include": [
    "**/*.d.ts"
]
```

Comment: vscode relies on the typescript language server (tsserver) and this of course needs tsconfigs. BUT the stories and specs should not slow down your normal build at all. maybe delete all specs and stories and compare it? these files could only be built if they are referenced from the production code (which they shouldnt be)

Comment: When I use include `**/*.d.ts I see a dramatic improvement.  Without that I see a massive slow down during build / hot reload.